# API for retrieving index P/E ratio?

Tags: stocks, market-indexes

Or CAPE ratio?

I would love to be able to pull the current P/E ratio for the S&P 500 into a spreadsheet, for example.

Neither the Google or Yahoo APIs have a P/E ratio associated with indices.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean the S&P 500 as a whole, you only have to take an ETF which tracks it. E.g. http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=IVV&region=usa&culture=en_US  now gives a Price/Prospective Earnings* 16.90

Comment: Yes, I was wondering there's a URL that would let me pull that into a spreadsheet. I believe both Google and Yahoo have shut down their free services now.

Comment: Ok. There are surely solutions from the usual suspects (Bloomberg, Thomson Reuters, Morningstar) but no idea how expensive. Bloomberg used to have something for free. https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/
Is it enough for you to scrape some ETF data from e.g. ETF.com? https://www.signalplot.com/scrape-data-1900-etfs/ Maybe there's something free in https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-stock-data or https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

Comment: Ah, there are also some API from certain ETF providers such as Blackrock. Didn't try: http://rockthecode.io/api/

Comment: Cool. I'll have a look. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any free APIs (which I assume you are looking for) that do the pre-calculation of that for you.  In Robert Shiller's book Irrational Exuberence he referenced data available on his website  (here: http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm), but it is not comprehensive or up to date.

You could however, using any APIs for individual stocks, calculate it for short periods of time. You would need to know the index members, their respective weights, and then fetch historical prices and earnings.

There are plenty of paid sources of this data. Xignite APIs could be used to get the core data pretty easily.  And in the past http://www.valueline.com has done this calculation for me, for a charge.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was pulling the S&P 100 into a spreadsheet from Yahoo. I calculate an evenly weighted average of those P/E ratios and that gives me some barometer of the market.