# P/E (or similar) for index funds?

Tags: stocks, index-fund, price-earnings-ratio

I'm looking to compare index funds, such as VTIVX vs VGTSX vs VFIAX, etc. 
I've found these posts that address P/E ratios for the S&P 500:

- [API for retrieving index P/E ratio?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/api-for-retrieving-index-p-e-ratio)
- [Where can I find S&P 500 P/E ratios?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/where-can-i-find-sp-500-p-e-ratios)

Do similar metrics exists for other index funds (especially globally diversified funds)?

Comment: If you are concerned with PE, why not buy a fund that actually has a value objective? I get your logic, but PE on funds is a really messy statistic, it will be very hard to use for comparisons between funds.

Comment: I don't see how it would be 'hard to use for comparisons between funds'. It might be difficult to calculate, but useful for comparisons IMO.

Answer (score 1):

ycharts.com has "Weighted Average PE Ratio" and a bunch of other metrics that are meant to correspond to well known stock metrics.  Other websites will have similar ratios.

Answer (score 0):

The S&P 500 is a market index.  The P/E data you're finding for the S&P 500 is data based on the constituent list of that market index and isn't necessarily the P/E ratio of a given fund, even one that aims to track the performance of the S&P 500.

I'm sure similar metrics exist for other market indexes, but unless Vanguard is publishing it's specific holdings in it's target date funds there's no market index to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Morningstar has this data, E.g.[VOO, Vanguard s&p500](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/voo/portfolio))